# Php wordpress how to replace spaces to hyphens in array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I need your help

I have an array mountain resorts in user meta

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(19) "Courchevel"
    [1]=>
    string(21) "Kitzbuhel"
    [2]=>
    string(14) "St Moritz"
  }
}
```

I use foreach

```
if (! empty($resorts)) {
    foreach ($resorts[0] as $value) {
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url(home_url( $value )) . ' class="link">' . $value . '</a>';
    }
}
```

But $value in href have spaces, like here localhost/St Moritz

How to replace all spaces to hyphens in href $value?

Thanks)

Comment: Have you tried anything? `str_replace` comes to mind

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if (! empty($resorts)) {
    foreach ($resorts[0] as $value) {
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url(home_url( sanitize_title($value))) . ' class="link">' . $value . '</a>';
    }
}
```

> Reference - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title

Comment: Why should the OP ___try this___? **Good answers** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer, and if it is well answered maybe they will upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (! empty($resorts)) {
    foreach ($resorts[0] as $value) {
        $value_for_text = $value;
        $value_for_url = $value;

        $url = explode(" ",$value);
        $final_url = "";
        if(is_array()){

            foreach($url as $url_text){
                $final_url .= $url_text;
            }
            echo '<a href="' . esc_url(home_url( $final_url )) . ' class="link">' . $value_for_text . '</a>';
        }
        else{
            echo '<a href="' . esc_url(home_url( $value )) . ' class="link">' . $value_for_text . '</a>';
        }        
    }
}
```

try this.
i hope this work for you. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The question is solved through the function str_replace

```
if (! empty($resorts)) {
    foreach ($resorts[0] as $value) {

        $spaces= array(" ");
        $value_url = str_replace($spaces, "-", $value);

        echo '<a href="' . esc_url(home_url( $value_url )) . ' class="link">' . $value . '</a>';
    }
}
```

Thanks all)